# Performance comparison between h2o and caddy web server

Tags: ssl, nginx, proxy, caddy

I'm thinking of replacing nginx as a ssl-proxy and as upstream server by something more simple.

Maybe caddy or h2o.
http://caddyserver.com
https://h2o.examp1e.net

Are there any benchmarks / performance comparison / setup experiences that compare these three browsers?

Which of them could be setup in the most secure way (as in "hard to exploit")?

All I need is:

- SSL-proxy w/ HTTP/2 support
- Serving static files
- Serving PHP-FPM applications
- Serving Python applications

Comment: FWIW, Caddy's crypto will be getting faster after Go 1.6 is released.

Comment: Just a note, you tagged this as "h2o", but the "h2o" tag is for another project, not the H2O web server.